# Rails / Ruby - HTML attribute problem -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a tooltip that use this html attribute "original-title".

I have tryed this:

```
content_tag(:span, '', :class => options[:pinfo_class], :original-title => options[:pinfo])
```

But it gives a error in view.

Then I have used this which works, but not with the tooltip.

```
content_tag(:span, '', :class => options[:pinfo_class], :original_title => options[:pinfo])
```

How do I force rails to use the :original-title ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a string as a hash key, like `'original-title' => options[:pinfo]`. Should work.

Also, most strings can be converted to symbols via `'some-string'.to_sym` method, or even defined as `:'some-string'`.